# How to pipe output of PHP to Linux command?

Tags: php, linux, pipe

I have a `PHP` script as tel.php which creates a `URL`(as $url). Now I want to use this `URL` as input of `Linux` script as myBashScript, something like this:

> php tel.php | myBashScript

How should I create the URL as output of `tel.php`?
For example, something like `file_get_contents($url)`

Comment: Your php script had to write on stdout. Did you try print or echo of the $url variable?